# Enum syntax errors in Visual Studio Code

Tags: apex, vs-code, enum

vscode is constantly giving me syntax errors when it comes to enum declarations. Do you know if there is any particular setting that I should switch so that the errors will disappear?

[image]

Comment: I recommend `public Enum Preference { OPT_IN, OPT_OUT }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IN` is [a reserved keyword](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_reserved_words.htm). You cannot use it in an enum (or anywhere outside of SOQL/SOSL, I believe).

The only way to fix this is to change your enum values (note that "inner" and "outer" are also reserved keywords).

Comment: And Apex is virtually the only language I know of that prohibits keywords in an enum. 

Comment: Yeah and this is kinda strange and a bit irritating.